# Creating grid style using isotope masonary

Tags: javascript, grid, jquery-masonry

I would like to add a masonry grid type style to my posts.
How would i do that?
And please let me know the script and a clear elaboration of putting classes into the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand you question, but i think this sample can help you
using isotope and some css
see sample at [CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/farnabaz/pen/tpakr)

Comment: That was handsome.Thanks.